# Tomcat8 & waffle integeration

Tags: java, tomcat, waffle

We are currently using waffle for authenticating our web based application build using java/j2ee. We are in the process of migrating the application to use Tomcat 8.We were initially using java 6 & tomcat 6 and the authentication worked fine. Now after the migration to java 8 & tomcat 8, We are unable to load the login page of the application. Im getting the below error.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FQN
at waffle.apache.WaffleAuthenticatorBase.<init>(WaffleAuthenticatorBase.java:44)
at waffle.apache.MixedAuthenticator.<init>(MixedAuthenticator.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

Im currently using waffle-tomcat8-1.7.3.jar file for the authentication.Please help us in resolving this issue. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include all dependencies for Waffle:

> Package Waffle JARs, including waffle-jna.jar, guava-18.0.jar,
>   jna-4.1.0.jar, jna-platform-4.1.0.jar, slf4j*.jar and
>   waffle-tomcat-6.jar in the application's lib directory or copy them to
>   Tomcat's lib.

https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/tomcat/TomcatSingleSignOnValve.md

Did you try also the newer 1.8 release?

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dblock.waffle/waffle-tomcat8/1.8.0